# How to calculate the share price after stock dilution, when the company is being taken over?

Tags: india, stock-valuation, equity, dilution

Currently, YES BANK might be taken over by SBI, and RBI has announced that SBI will get 49% equity at no less than 10 rs per share. YES BANK shares are currently trading at 16.60. There are currently 2,550,472,231 shares, with a net value of 4233.78 crores (42.3378 billions rs).
The RBI plans to alter the authorized capital for the reconstructed bank to ₹5,000 crores and the number of equity shares will also be altered to 2,400 crores of ₹2 each aggregating to ₹4,800 crores.
More details are given here: https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/banks-private-sector/yesbank/YB

What would be the share value of YES bank after this stock dilution?

Comment: "SBI will get 49% equity" What's happening with the other 51%? What's SBI currently trading at (rs/share and total shares outstanding)? Is this a stock swap rather than cash sale?

Comment: New shares will be issued by YES bank, which will be bought by SBI, such that SBI has 49% equity.